# What to do if a webpage on the dark web is blocked because I need to enable JavaScript

Tags: darknet

Having JavaScript enabled on the dark web is suicide, but what should one do if a site displays a big poster saying "JavaScript needs to be enabled to access this site"?

Comment: Don't do it, unless you know its safe or dedicate a computer to shady sites if you have to go to them.

Comment: See also: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40620/why-is-javascript-disabled-in-the-tor-browser-bundle

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript on its own *shouldn't* be a problem in the context of a darkweb browser such as Tor. The browser is configured to use a proxy and JavaScript can't magically get around that in order to reveal your real IP.

The problem is that JavaScript *can* be used as part of exploits. If there's a vulnerability in your browser, a malicious page might be able to exploit it in order to get code execution on your box, or otherwise perform operations that deanonymise you.

If you trust the site and you're accessing it over HTTPS, feel free to run JavaScript on it. Shouldn't be a problem. If you're accessing over plain HTTP then I would be more concerned, because a malicious exit node could inject malicious JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. What if I use Qubes with Whonix? Is it safe then?

Comment: @hf4KlwoP2fm2 the OS doesn't matter if the threat is browser exploits

Comment: If the browser can make outbound network requests then they could deanonymise you without worrying about what your host OS is.

Comment: @Polynomial Is it a good idea then to connect to Tor first, without a VPN, and then VPN over Tor? I've heard that if one connects to VPN->Tor, if the VPN gets compromised, one's real IP address can be revealed. But what if Tor gets compromised, e.g. if the entry node gets hacked? Then the attacker will know my real IP, right?

Comment: @hf4KlwoP2fm2 I generally do not recommend using both a VPN and Tor unless you have problems with connecting to Tor directly because of government interference.

Comment: Isn't it safer to connect to a VPN after Tor, so that the data goes through entry node->middle node->exit node->VPN? That way, the VPN IP will be shown on the web, and anyone who tries to find one's real IP has to break one more layer.

Comment: No. VPNs are not a privacy tool, despite the marketing. Stick to Tor on its own.

Comment: @Polynomial What if the entry node gets hacked? Won't my real IP be visible to the hacker/government? Is it possible to run Tor->Tor?

Comment: @hf4KlwoP2fm2 I think you need to work on your threat model a bit. If the government wants to come after you specifically [they'll get to you some way or another](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/1401_08-12_mickens.pdf). Compromising entry nodes will reveal your IP but only the fact that you're using Tor; the entry node can't see the destination or the content you send. Compromising exit nodes only reveals the target and content (which may be encrypted if you use HTTPS) but doesn't reveal your IP. They generally need to compromise many nodes to deanonymise your activities.

Answer (score 1):

What's a great way to get someone to run your malicious JavaScript? Tell them they need to enable JavaScript to continue.

If you absolutely must continue and you believe the site to be potentially hostile, treat it as such. That means taking steps such as using a VM, perhaps on a machine that you will wipe afterwards to counter risks of something escaping.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a suspicious site that you absolutely have to go to, you should use a computer that you would not care about if it was infected.

You could also try a VM, but technically that is hackable. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine_escape

Comment: Thanks. What if I use Qubes with Whonix? Is it safe then?

Comment: Not 100%. No VM is going to be.